# Removing domain labels Androidplot

Tags: androidplot

I'm trying to remove the domain labels in my AndroidPlot bar graph. I've tried using `plot.getGraphWidget().getDomainLabelPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);` as suggested in another post, but the current AndroidPlot version does not seem to include this method.

Is there another way for removing the domain labels?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Androidplot 1.x you can do this in your plot's xml by adding:

```
ap:lineLabelTextColorBottom="@color/ap_transparent"
```

Or programatically in your Java code:

```
plot.getGraph().getLineLabelStyle(XYGraphWidget.Edge.BOTTOM).getPaint().setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```